# Save value and pass it

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

```
<a href="About" id="myLink" onclick="get()"> @item.cd </a>
```

From this link I need to save the value "cd" when I click it and then pass this value to another page to feed it to a query. I tried different solutions but without results and now I do not know how to do it.

Comment: I forgot to mention that this project is developed in asp.net in c#

Answer (score 0):

You can pass `cd` as argument of the onclick function. Along with this you need to pass event object to prevent the default behavior of the anchor tag.

Inside the function use `window.location` to navigate to new url

```js
function get(e, elem) {
  e.preventDefault();
  window.location = 'yourURL/' + elem

}
```

```html
<a href="About" id="myLink" onclick="get(event,'cd')"> @item.cd </a>
```

Comment: I have to write this function on the second page, right?

Comment: In the first page

Comment: Does this just pass the string '`cd`' -- or does asp.net do some magic to let javascipt access the bound string `@item.cd` that represents?

Comment: I need to pass this string a variable on the second page because the latter must be inserted in the  where condition of a query

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways

**USE JS**

- store `cd`'s value in web storage
- push it to link (i.e: http://url?cd=value)
- or directly put `<a href="About?cd=value" id="myLink" onclick="get()"> @item.cd </a>`

then you can get it by JS on the new page.

**USE C#**

create a function for `GET` method, when you click the link, submit `cd`'s value then get it on the new page. Since I'm not sure which kind of .net you use, I can't give a more clearly solution.